# Count the number of statements in JavaScript and TypeScript files

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to count the number of statements in JavaScript and TypeScript files. Is there any tool that could help me to do that? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [Espree](https://github.com/eslint/espree) for JavaScript code or [@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/main/packages/typescript-estree) for TypeScript to analyze the contents of the files. They give an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) that you could then analyze and use to count the number of statements.